# Using Jacobian matrix in solve_ivp

Tags: python, solver

I am trying to use the solve_ivp built-in function with the Jacobian matrix. 
I get this error message:

> UserWarning: The following arguments have no effect for a chosen solver: `jac`.
>     .format(", ".join("`{}`".format(x) for x in extraneous)))

I am unsure if it is a syntax error or an error in the Jacobian matrix.

Some of my code

```
def MyIntFun(t,y):
    return DivWatFlux(y,t,wPar, sPar, RPar,dzIN, dzN)

def jacfunc(t,y):
    jac = Richardsmatrix(y, t, wPar, sPar, RPar, dzIN, dzN)
    return jac

mt.tic()
hwODE = spi.solve_ivp(MyIntFun, [tout[0], tout[-1]], hw0, method='RK45', 
    vectorized=True,rtol=1e-4, jac=jacfunc) 
mt.toc()
```

This is the code for the Jacobian:

```
def Richardsmatrix(hw, t, wPar, sPar, RPar, dzIN, dzN): #the jacobian (a,b,c)

    K=Kfun(hw, wPar, m)
    kRes =RPar.kRobBotR

    a = np.zeros(nN)
    b = np.zeros(nN)
    c = np.zeros(nN)


    ii=np.arange(1, nN-1)

    a[ii] = K[ii, 0]/(dzIN[ii, 0]*dzN[ii-1, 0]) #middle nodes
    a[0] = 0 #a1l is zero and not in matrix 
    a[nN-1] = K[nN-1, 0] / (dzIN[nN-1, 0] * dzN[nN-2, 0]) 

    b[ii] = -K[ii, 0] / (dzIN[ii,0] * dzN[ii-1,0])- K[ii+1,0] / (dzIN[ii,0] * dzN[ii, 0]) #middle nodes
    b[0] = -K[1, 0]/(dzIN[0 , 0]*dzN[0, 0])- kRes / dzIN[0 ,0]
    b[nN-1] = -K[nN-1, 0] / (dzIN[nN-1, 0] * dzN[nN-2, 0])

    c[ii] = K[ii+1,0] / (dzIN[ii,0] * dzN[ii, 0]) #middle nodes
    c[0] = K[1,0] / (dzIN[0, 0] * dzN[0, 0]) 
    c[nN-1] = 0

    B = np.diag(a[1:nN], -1)+ np.diag(b, 0) + np.diag(c[0:nN-1], 1)
    sB = sp.sparse.csc_matrix(B)
    return
```

My group and I are pretty new at programming, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There are two separate issues.

First, when `method='RK45'` is passed to `solve_ivp`, the solver (In this case, Runge-Kutta 4/5) cannot make use of the Jacobian. Try passing `solver='Radau'`, `solver='BDF'`, or `solver='LSODA'`, since these make use of the Jacobian, per the [documentation](http://scipy.github.io/devdocs/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html?highlight=integrate%20solve_ivp#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) (in particular, the `jac` keyword argument is documented).

The other issue that I see is that the `Richardsmatrix` function you have there has a return statement that does not return anything. You might want to try `return sB` instead (assuming that `sB` is the matrix you want the function to return).